# Calling C# method within a Java program

Tags: c#, java, c++, java-native-interface, wrapper

C# methods cannot be called directly in Java using JNI due to different reasons. So first we have to write a wrapper for C# using C++ then create the dll and use it through JNI in Java.

I have problem in calling C# code in C++. I'm adding C# `.netmodule` file to a C++ project. Code is pasted below. Please guide me if i'm doing anything wrong.

This is my managed C++ class `UsbSerialNum.h`:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#include <iostream>
#using "UsbSerialNumberCSharp.netmodule"

using namespace std;

using namespace System;

public __gc class UsbSerialNum
{
    public:

        UsbSerialNumberCSharp::UsbSerialNumberCSharp __gc *t;

        UsbSerialNum() {
            cout<<"Hello from C++";
            t = new UsbSerialNumberCSharp::UsbSerialNumberCSharp();
        }

        void CallUsbSerialNumberCSharpHello() {
            t->hello();
        }
};
```

C# `UsbSerialNumberCSharp.cs` file from which i've created the `.netmodule` file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace UsbSerialNumberCSharp
{
    public class UsbSerialNumberCSharp
    {

        public UsbSerialNumberCSharp(){
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }

        public static void hello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }

        public void helloCSharp ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("helloCSharp");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main `makeDLL.cpp` file from which `makeDLL.dll` is created:

```
#include "jni.h"
#include <iostream>


// This is the java header created using the javah -jni command.
#include "testDLL.h"


// This is the Managed C++ header that contains the call to the C#
#include "UsbSerialNum.h"

using namespace std;


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_testDLL_hello
(JNIEnv *, jobject) {

    // Instantiate the MC++ class.
    UsbSerialNum* serial = new UsbSerialNum();
    serial->CallUsbSerialNumberCSharpHello();
}
```

Here is my java class:

```
public class testDLL {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("makeDLL");
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //        new testDLL().GetUSBDevices("SCR3", 100);
        new testDLL().hello();
    }

    public native void hello();

}
```

**EDIT:**

If i simply ignore the call to UsbSerial.h in my main file i.e. use simple C++ then my code is working fine in Java. Basically C++ managed class is not working properly.
Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: at which point you are getting the error?

Comment: What's the problem? Is this managed C++? I don't recognize the `__gc` bits

Comment: i've edited the question. please check it out. thanks.

Comment: @BumbleBee: when pointer of UsbSerial serial* is created and constructor is called. That is where i'm getting the error.

Comment: @flipchart: __gc is used to make a garbage collectable instance to be compatible with java...

Comment: If this is for Java, then the `c#` tag is wrong

Comment: @flipchart: actually problem is with the C#, C++ classes not with java. (i guess)

Comment: Why don't you import the C++ classes instead of getting what basically amounts to twice the work.  Just convert your C# dll to java...

Comment: @Ramhound: Can't use C# dll directly in java. It does not work...

Comment: @Justin: Error message is displayed when i call the function in java. It is some kind of excess violation...

Comment: Access violation is about as a generic error as you can get in C++ world. "__gc is used to make a garbage collectable instance to be compatible with java" - this part does not make sense: you cannot have the Java GC manage anything outside of the Java VM, so it's probably going to make more harm than good.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more?... Which API are you trying to use?

Comment: @UmerHayat: What i want actually is to get the serial number of connected usb device and for this i'm querying WMI in C# and trying to use it in Java through JNI..

Comment: @UmerHayat: There is no specific API in C#. I'm using some built-in namespace `System.Management`..

Answer (score 8):

It would be useful to know what you need this interoperability for exactly. In any case, you should look into [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/index.html); alternatively you can (as has been suggested for a similar problem) use COM as a bridge: expose the C#/CLR as a COM interface and then use [com4j](http://com4j.java.net/) in Java.

Comment: I want to get the serial number of all attached USBs, have already written the code in C#, want to use it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid C# and still can query WMI using C++ only. See [Using WMI to call method on objects](http://win32easy.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-wmi-to-call-method-on-objects.html)