# How to call C# function from java

Tags: java, c#, c++

I need to call C# function from java and to this I have created the following.
I have a create a java header file Authenticator.h , here is the code:

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Authenticator */

#ifndef _Included_Authenticator
#define _Included_Authenticator
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Authenticator
 * Method:    authenticate
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
 */
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_Authenticator_authenticate
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I have then create a C# function that Authenticate

```
namespace SharpAuthenticator
{
    public class Authenticator
    {



        public  bool Authenticate(String username,String password)
        {
            return username == "user" && password == "login";
        }

    }
}
```

Then I am trying to call the C# function from C++(project to create a dll) using the code below;

```
String^ toString(const char *str)
{
    int len = (int)strlen(str);
    array<unsigned char>^ a = gcnew array<unsigned char>(len);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        a[i] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    return Encoding::UTF8->GetString(a);
}
bool authenticate(const char *username, const char *password)
{
     SharpAuthenticator::Authenticator::Authenticate(toString(username), toString(password));

}
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_Authenticator_authenticate
(JNIEnv *env, jobject c, jstring name, jstring pass)
{
    jboolean result;

    jboolean isCopyUsername;
    const char * username = env->GetStringUTFChars(name, &isCopyUsername);
    jboolean isCopypassword;
    const char * password = env->GetStringUTFChars(pass, &isCopypassword);

    result = authenticate(username, password);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(name, username);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pass, password);
    return result;
}
```

And finnally create a dll that i need to call from java. The dll is created and I load it well in java but I get this error log in java. What could I be Missing.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=9708, tid=7756
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x812f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

Comment: Check This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181344/calling-c-sharp-method-within-a-java-program

Comment: @phantom I dont have much knowledge using c++. could help me how I can call the C# function from C++

Comment: I'll try but not right now maybe in 2 hours.

Comment: I will be glad, I have tried that for the last two days and cant get a solution

Comment: Have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474398/how-to-use-c-sharp-function-in-java-using-jna-lib it looks pretty easy

Comment: @phantom I still need Your help am not good in C# or C++ I have skills only in java and I have a device that I need to communicate to and the functions are written in C#

Comment: @MorganM Have you ever checked this out: http://jni4net.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all lets create a C# file like this:

```
using System;
public class Test{
  public Test(){}
  public String ping(){
    return "C# is here.";
  }
}
```

Then compile this with command below:

```
csc.exe /target:module Test.cs
```

You can find `csc.exe` in install path of .NET framework. After that create java file:

```
public class Test{
  public native String ping();
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.load("/path/to/dll");
    System.out.println("Java is running.");
    Test t = new Test();
    System.out.println("Trying to catch C# " + r.ping());
  }
}
```

`javac Test.java` This generates a `Test.class`.

`javah -jni Test` This generates a `Test.h` file which will be included in
C++ code.

After that we need to create our C++ file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "JAVA/Test.h"
#include "MCPP/Test.h"
#pragma once
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "Test.netmodule"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Test_ping(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
  Test^ t = gcnew Test();
  String^ ping = t->ping();
  char* str = static_cast<char*>((System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(ping)).ToPointer());

  char cap[128];
  strcpy_s(cap, str);

  return env->NewStringUTF(cap);
}
```

Finally:

```
c:\>java Test
```

I hope this helps you. A basic example to use function C# in Java.

Sources:
https://www.quora.com/How-common-is-the-problem-of-calling-C-methods-from-Java-Do-many-developers-come-across-such-necessity

Comment: I have created the C# and java file and compiled my problem is this part of C++ where do I include it #using "Test.netmodule" am using visual studio 2013

Comment: Am still getting this error
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=5800, tid=5792
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x812f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as: